# What does repair do?

Tags: validator, core-technology, core

In the `replay` stage in the Solana validator, there's a step called repair. What does this do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repair is all about fetching "missing" shreds in order to complete and replay blocks. The repair service is constantly trying to fetch those shreds from the network and putting them in the blockstore for eventual replay.

During replay, there's an extra bit to notify the repair service about slots with conflicting or duplicate blots, so that the repair service fetches the "correct" version of the shreds.

You can read more about repair at https://docs.solana.com/implemented-proposals/repair-service